# new bridge setup for lxd on fresh host 16.04 and fresh guest 16.04

Tags: networking, lxd

I am still struggling with an lxd bridge setup for IPv4 for all completely new ubuntu 16.04 installs, hosts and guests.  There is one ethernet adapter on the host, and it needs to be shared by its guests (no NAT!).  the 16.04 new guests are all webservers that need to pick up their own IP addresses from the DHCP network server.  my host boots 16.04 up with an **eno1** internet identified by ifconfig (I am never sure when eth0, eth1, or eno1 are needed).  I want the bridge configuration to be permanent forever, and reemerge upon host reboot.

to install, on the fresh host

```
host# apt install lxd
host# lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 first
host# lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 second
host# # lxc list
```

I think the needed steps somehow involve the following:

- stopping the running containers with lxc
- a change of the /etc/network/interfaces file
- possibly shutting down containers now and/or host networking
- a dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd  (what exact answers?)
- an /etc/init.d/networking restart
- starting the running containers with lxc

I am happy to reinstall yet again---I already did this many times, because I am never sure whether my attempts have screwed up something else.  it's painful.  part of this is that I follow certain guides which seem to move along and then somewhere flunk me.

given that I will not have altered *anything*, how is such a super-plain bridge setup accomplished most easily out of the box for hosts and guests??

help appreciated.

sincerely, /iaw

Answer (score 0):

Before using LXD, you have to configure a custom bridge by [following these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging). You may also want to set the `dns-search` and `dns-nameservers`options in the `interfaces` file.

Then run `sudo lxd init`. Configure storage, network and password settings according to your needs. At the end answer "yes" to the question "Do you want to configure the LXD bridge (yes/no)?". In the following dialog answer "No" when asked to configure the *default* LXD bridge. Then answer "Yes" when asked to use an *existing* bridge. As "Bridge interface name" enter `br0` or whatever you called it in `/etc/network/interface`. Then `lxc launch` your container and it will obtain an IP address from your DHCP server.